# Nginx unable to load static files from django

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

family, Im having a little trouble to make nginx server load static file collected by django. here is my nginx sites-available

```
server {
        listen 80;
       server_name <my_ip_address>;

    location / {

           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $server_name;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

        }

  location /asset/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /var/www/html/dev2_assets/;
           }
  }
```

Down here is my Django STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT configurations

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/dev2_assets/'
```

When i run the application with ./manage.py runserver its loads all the static files. Any help. Thanks

Comment: `/asset/` != `/assets/`

Comment: Thanks Dan, let me check clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your Location.

Your not specifying a root for it, also in your settings.py your declaring assets but in your location your declaring asset with a missing s. try changing it to something like this:

```
location /assets/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /var/www/html/dev2_assets;
    }
```

Also for debugging purposes try added this above location:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

Then you will get a specific error message about it not being able to retrive your static files.

Lastly are you sure your utilyzing nginx, django, and gunicorn correct?

Here is a copy of my site file for comparison:
    # This redirects all incoming traffic on port 80 to 443
    server {
           listen         80;
           server_name    domain.com;
           return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

```
server {

listen   443;

ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domain.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domain.com.key;

server_name helius.dk;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
#location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
        root /home/user/projectname/static;
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/projectname/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, let me try that i will get back

Comment: error log shows that Nginx is asking for  static files from 
   /var/www/html/dev2_assets/assets/, I havent notice where Im doing wrong.

Comment: I got it working, I have changed `root -> alias`, also i have added `error_log `/var/log/nginx/error.log;` in the nginx sites-enable, I also changed corrected the mistake for asset to assets, Thanks @Alexander and @Daniel Roseman